# Share or collect xubuntu keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys

Since I moved from Windows to Xubuntu as my work and personal OS, I tweaked a lot of keyboard shortcuts and now I'm feeling very comfortable with it.

I have two different users on this computer and I would really love to share those shortcuts and maybe keep them synchronized somehow.

Also exporting and importing them would be nice enough right now.

Is there any way via command line or via some software?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts are stored in the XML file

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

Comment: And importing is just replacing that file with our version?